# C4512 assignment operator could not be generated

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, warnings, copy-assignment

I'm working on updating an old C++ application, it is being compiled with MSVC 2013, not the latest I know.

I'm getting a warning:

```
1>c:\fraenkelsoftware-millikan\shared\debug\debughelper.h(84): warning C4512: 'HowLong' : assignment operator could not be generated
1>          c:\fraenkelsoftware-millikan\shared\debug\debughelper.h(65) : see declaration of 'HowLong'
```

Here is the class prototype:

```
class HowLong {
public:
    /// \param  Duration of what we are trying to measure
    HowLong(const std::string &a_str, IDebug::Severity a_sev = Sev_Debug):
            m_start(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time()),
                m_str(a_str), m_sev(a_sev) {
    }
    /// Destructor outputs how long the object was alive
    ~HowLong() {
        boost::posix_time::time_duration elapsed(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time() - m_start);
        DEBUG_LOG(m_sev, m_str + " took: " + boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(elapsed));
    }

private:
    const boost::posix_time::ptime m_start; ///< Start time
    const std::string m_str;                ///< Duration of what we are trying to measure
    const IDebug::Severity m_sev;
};
```

I haven't seen this warning before and I'm not sure what it actually means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class has constant private data members

```
const boost::posix_time::ptime m_start; ///< Start time
const std::string m_str;                ///< Duration of what we are trying to measure
const IDebug::Severity m_sev;
```

You may not reassign constant objects. So the compiler issues a message that it is unable to generate a default copy assignment operator that makes member-wise assignments.

Comment: Doesn't the const keyword mean that the variable remains constant and cannot change after assignment?  Since no assignment is made until the constructor aren't they still valid?

Comment: Obviously when this was originally written the compiler allowed it, not now.

Comment: @SPlatten A constant variable may not be changed after its initialization. It is undefined behavior if the compiler allows to use its default copy assignment operator for such objects.

Answer (score 2):

Different example, similar effect:

```
struct foo { const int x = 42;};

int main() {
    foo f,g;
    f = g;
}
```

`foo` has no compiler generated assignment operator, because you cannot assign to a `const` member.

However, in the above it is causing an error (`g` cannot be assigned to `f`). I have to admit, that I have no clue how to get a warning only and I suppose the code that actually does trigger the warning is not in the part you posted.